# HttP url problem to read xml data in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

if you copy http://tgbs.ir/xml/Category.xml in your browser , you will see content of xml file. but in below code alert doesnt show and i think url doesnt work .
please help me to solve this problem because this code has to read from this url.

```
Date.ReadCategoryXml = function() {
    var counter=0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://tgbs.ir/xml/Category.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find("category").each(function() {
                var cTitle = $(this).find("title").text()
                var cUrl = $(this).find("url").text();
                Data.arrCategory[counter++]= new Category(cTitle,cUrl);
            });
            alert("behnaz");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using jsonp to get cross domain calls
More info @ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Example

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://tgbs.ir/xml/Category.xml',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function( data ) {
      alert("Success : "+data);
  }
});
```

Comment: i have an error ! firebug show me "XML can't be the whole program"

Comment: i have an error ! firebug show me "XML can't be the whole program" . and when alert error , show message " parse error ".this xml file include tags:

<item>

 <category>

  <title>sport</title>

  <url>xml/sport.xml</url>

 </category>

 <category>

  <title>cinema</title>

  <url>xml/cinema.xml</url>

 </category>

  <category>

  <title>language</title>

  <url>xml/language.xml</url>

 </category>

 <category>

  <title>country</title>

  <url>xml/country.xml</url>

 </category>
 
</item>

Comment: It seems it expecting an script json object instead of xml. Try YQL or https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins to load cross domain xml.

Answer (score 1):

http://tgbs.ir the Domain where the script runs? If not… You can't load xml data from an other Domain because of the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Possible Solution: [craigslist rss feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695316/craigslist-rss-feed/7067888#7067888)

In short... you have to build a wrapper function which gets your data.

Comment: so how can i load xml data from this url? do you have any suggestion for me ?

Comment: Sure... You only have to read my Answer (Possible Solution) :)