# cant get json with jquery getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, callback

I have a web service and I'm trying to get data by JSON. if I access within the same server works fine but when I upload it to the hosting it doesn't work. the problem is the "?callback=?" param. with chrome i see the returned json but the code below didn't show it in the input text:

```
   <html><head> <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {   
            $("#cons").click(function(){
                alert("wait");
                var nombre = $("#nombre").attr('value');
                if(nombre!==''){
                    var today = new Date();
                    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                    $.getJSON("http://grup15.mihost.info/index.php/WS/Api/user/nombre/"+nombre+"/ano/"+ yyyy +"/mes/"+mm+"/format/json?callback=?", function(data) {

                        var htmlResult = "";
                        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            htmlResult += val.total;
                        });

                        $('#gasto').attr('value',htmlResult);
                    });
                }else{
                    alert("Nombre Necesario");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="nombre" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gasto De este mes:</td>
            <td><input id="gasto" type="text" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><button id="cons" type="button">Consultar</button></td></tr>
    </table>


</body>
```

If i delete the "?callback=? chrome shows: "not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
what i have to do??? thanks for the help!

Comment: Does your server handle JSONP? The request would need to parse the callback function name and wrap the request in a JavaScript function of that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?callback=?` means JSONP, which means the server should return JSONP, not JSON.

JSONP is actually a script, that looks like so:

```
func({data: 123, test: 456});
```

Your data needs to be wrapped in the value of the `callback` parameter.

Comment: how can i wrap the data in the value of callback parameter?? thanks!

Comment: @Roomm: Read value of the `callback` parameter (it's a GET variable), and then print a string like: `func({data:12})`.  Here's a PHP example: `echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $data . ')';`.

Comment: @Roomm: You need to edit the "Web Service" on the __server__ to work with JSONP (in JavaScript on the __client__).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make AJAX requests cross-domain like this. Use **JSONP** instead.

Comment: He _is_ using JSONP, `$.getJSON` uses JSONP when you add `?callback=?`.

Comment: I think the syntax may be confusing jQuery "json?callback=?" should be "jsoncallback=?"

Comment: I don't think the syntax is a problem, it's a valid URL.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript adheres to the "same origin" policy, as described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

This is a security measure to prevent cross-site scripting.

You might consider workarounds discussed here:
[Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: He's using JSONP, the `?callback=?` makes jQuery use JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make a JSONP you could build a wrapper function to fetch your data. Maybe via PHP.

Take a look: [craigslist rss feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695316/craigslist-rss-feed/7067888#7067888). My solution is build to work with XML but ist should be easily converted to work with JSON.